# Dynamic breadcrumbs using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There is very good example of how to make a [breadcrumbs on site in examples folder of react-router repo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/breadcrumbs/app.js). But I'm wondering how to make breadcrumbs with dynamic routes.

Assume we have this configuration:

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/projects" component={ProjectsApp}>
        <IndexRoute component={ProjectsDashboard} />
        <Route path=":projectId" component={ProjectBoard}>
            <Route path=":taskId" component={ProjectTaskBoard}>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I want to make something like this:

*Projects(link to '/projects') -> MyAwesomeProject (link to '/projects/11'. Title taken from somewhere (from store by id from routeParams or by another way)) -> MyTask (link to '/projects/11/999')*

How can I achieve this result? Are there any best practices? Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old question but there is a component for react-router to support this, take a look: https://github.com/svenanders/react-breadcrumbs hope it helps

Answer (score 9):

We use the package [react-breadcrumbs-dynamic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-breadcrumbs-dynamic) which is most

flexible for any router (included react-router v4).

```
import {
  BreadcrumbsProvider,
  Breadcrumbs,
  BreadcrumbsItem
} from 'react-breadcrumbs-dynamic'

const theApp = (
  <BreadcrumbsProvider>
    <App />
  </BreadcrumbsProvider>
)

const App = (props) => (
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Breadcrumbs/>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

const Page = (props) => (
  <div>
    <BreadcrumbsItem to='/'>Main Page</BreadcrumbsItem>
    {props.children}
    <Route exact path="/user" component={User} />
  </div>
)


const User = (props) => (
  <div>
    <BreadcrumbsItem to='/user'>Home</BreadcrumbsItem>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)
```

The repo is here: [react-breadcrumbs-dynamic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-breadcrumbs-dynamic)

Comment: Will the bread crumb items automatically update with browser back and forward actions

Comment: 2022 (router v6) now has facilities built-in to make this easier. See https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches#breadcrumbs

Answer (score 2):

> With react-router v4, all routes are dynamic (although I think there are still options to write static definitions).

As mentioned by @tbo in there comment, react-breadcrumbs was an ok solution for implementing this with version 3 of react-router. There were even some workarounds for the dynamic breadcrumbs you describe (e.g. using the `prepend` or `getDisplayName` props).

There is a conversation going on [in this issue](https://github.com/svenanders/react-breadcrumbs/issues/99) to determine how to best support react-router v4 which definitely ties into your question as well. I've dug through a bunch of other breadcrumbs component repositories which all seem to struggle from with the same static route issues, some having similar issues open for figuring out v4 support.

*TLDR; If you're still on react-router v3, you can probably make the react-breadcrumbs package work for dynamic breadcrumbs. If you've migrated to v4, stay tuned and I'll hopefully have a better answer soon.*

#### Update

After finding no other solutions that fit my needs I developed a solution and opened a [pull request](https://github.com/svenanders/react-breadcrumbs/pull/105) on the react-breadcrumbs repository. [Auto-breadcrumb](https://github.com/likun7981/auto-breadcrumb), as mentioned below, and [this discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4556) are also potential solutions but allow less customization. If you need more customization, subscribe to and feel free to comment on or help with the pr.

#### Update (2020)

That pull request was merged, and [react-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/svenanders/react-breadcrumbs) now works great for `react-router` version 4 and up.

Comment: Will the bread crumb items automatically update with browser back and forward actions

Comment: Yes, they will. Updated my answer as well to reflect the current state of `react-breadcrumbs`.

Comment: 2022 (router v6) now has facilities built-in to make this easier. See https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches#breadcrumbs

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, and several open-source solutions (see answers here as well: [How do I create react-router v4 breadcrumbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380448/how-do-i-create-react-router-v4-breadcrumbs))

Personally, I prefer a HOC solution because of the small surface area, rendering flexibility, and readable breadcrumb route config.

`Breadcrumbs.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withBreadcrumbs } from 'withBreadcrumbs';

const UserBreadcrumb = ({ match }) =>
  <span>{match.params.userId}</span>; // use match param userId to fetch/display user name

const routes = [
  { path: 'users', breadcrumb: 'Users' },
  { path: 'users/:userId', breadcrumb: UserBreadcrumb},
  { path: 'something-else', breadcrumb: ':)' },
];

const Breadcrumbs = ({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <div>
    {breadcrumbs.map(({ breadcrumb, path, match }) => (
      <span key={path}>
        <NavLink to={match.url}>
          {breadcrumb}
        </NavLink>
        <span>/</span>
      </span>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default withBreadcrumbs(routes)(Breadcrumbs);
```

`withBreadcrumbs.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { matchPath, withRouter } from 'react-router';

const renderer = ({ breadcrumb, match }) => {
  if (typeof breadcrumb === 'function') { return breadcrumb({ match }); }
  return breadcrumb;
};

export const getBreadcrumbs = ({ routes, pathname }) => {
  const matches = [];

  pathname
    .replace(/\/$/, '')
    .split('/')
    .reduce((previous, current) => {
      const pathSection = `${previous}/${current}`;

      let breadcrumbMatch;

      routes.some(({ breadcrumb, path }) => {
        const match = matchPath(pathSection, { exact: true, path });

        if (match) {
          breadcrumbMatch = {
            breadcrumb: renderer({ breadcrumb, match }),
            path,
            match,
          };
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      });

      if (breadcrumbMatch) {
        matches.push(breadcrumbMatch);
      }

      return pathSection;
    });

  return matches;
};

export const withBreadcrumbs = routes => Component => withRouter(props => (
  <Component
    {...props}
    breadcrumbs={
      getBreadcrumbs({
        pathname: props.location.pathname,
        routes,
      })
    }
  />
));
```

Open-source HOC is also available here:
https://github.com/icd2k3/react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution providing single source of truth for nested navigation and breadcrumbs.

The example app is available on GitHub: https://github.com/sneas/react-nested-routes-example

Demo: https://sneas.github.io/react-nested-routes-example/

Navigation configuration:

```
export const navigation = [
  {
    path: "/",
    label: "All categories",
    content: () => <AllCategories />,
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/electronics",
        label: "Electronics",
        content: () => <Electronics />,
        routes: [
          {
            path: "/accessories",
            label: "Accessories",
            content: () => <Accessories />,
            routes: [
              {
                path: "/usb-cables",
                label: "USB cables",
                content: () => <UsbCables />
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: "/headphones",
            label: "Headphones",
            content: () => <Headphones />
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

We have to recursively flatten navigation and render it a flat array:

```
const routes = flattenRoutes(navigation);
return (<Router>
  {routes.map((route, index) => (
    <Route
      key={index}
      path={route.path}
      render={() => rouete.content}
    ></Route>
  ))}
</Router>);
```

Then build breadcrumbs out of the same navigation structure.

Answer (score 1):

[Auto-Breadcrumb](https://github.com/likun7981/auto-breadcrumb/) seems to be the best option if you're on version 4 of React Router. I've yet to find a great tutorial but there is an uncommented, but fairly [simple demo](https://github.com/likun7981/auto-breadcrumb/tree/master/demo) available.

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse this component

```js
import React from 'react'
import BreadCrumbs from './BreadCrumbs/BreadCrumbs'



const MainLayout = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <p><BreadCrumbs/></p>
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </>
    )
}

export default MainLayout
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import Breadcrumbs from '@mui/material/Breadcrumbs';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

const BreadCrumbs = () => {
    const location = useLocation()
    const path = location.pathname.split(/[/]/);
    console.log("location", path)

    return (
        <>
            <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
                {path.map((p) => <Link underline="hover" color="inherit">{p}</Link>).slice(0, path.length - 1)}
                {path.map((p) => <Typography color="black">{p}</Typography>).slice(path.length - 1)}
            </Breadcrumbs>
        </>
    )
}

export default BreadCrumbs
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './toptag.css';
import { useLocation, NavLink as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Breadcrumbs, Typography, Link } from '@mui/material';
import { Grain, Whatshot, Home } from '@mui/icons-material';

function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\b\w+/g, function (s) {
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase()
  })
}

export default function Toptag() {
  let location = useLocation()
  const pathnames = location.pathname.split('/').filter((x) => x)

  return (
    <div role="presentation" onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
      <div className="topNavigator">
        <div className="pTag">
          <Breadcrumbs aria-label='Breadcrumb'>
            {
              pathnames.map((value, index) => {
                const last = index === pathnames.length - 1;
                const to = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')}`;

                return last ?
                  (
                    <Typography
                      sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}
                      color="red"
                    >
                      {value === 'home' ?
                        < Home sx={{ mr: 0.5 }} fontSize="inherit" />
                        :
                        < Grain sx={{ mr: 0.5 }} fontSize="inherit" />
                      }
                      {toTitleCase(value)}
                    </Typography>
                  )
                  :
                  (
                    <Link color='inherit' component={RouterLink} to={to} >
                      <Typography color={value === 'home' ? 'black' : 'green'} sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }} >
                        {value === 'home' ?
                          < Home sx={{ mr: 0.5 }} fontSize="inherit" />
                          :
                          < Whatshot sx={{ mr: 0.5 }} fontSize="inherit" />
                        }
                        {toTitleCase(value)}
                      </Typography>
                    </Link>
                  )
              })
            }
          </Breadcrumbs>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is a better answer than the many existing ones? Thanks.