# How do I create react-router v4 breadcrumbs?

Tags: react-router-v4

How do I create react-router v4 breadcrumbs? I tried asking this question on the react-router V4 website via an issue ticket. They just said to see the [recursive paths](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/recursive-paths) example. I really want to create it in [semantic-ui-react](http://react.semantic-ui.com)

Answer (score 30):

I was after the same thing and your question pointed me in the right direction.

This worked for me:

```
const Breadcrumbs = (props) => (
    <div className="breadcrumbs">
        <ul className='container'>
            <Route path='/:path' component={BreadcrumbsItem} />
        </ul>
    </div>
)

const BreadcrumbsItem = ({ match, ...rest }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <li className={match.isExact ? 'breadcrumb-active' : undefined}>
            <Link to={match.url || ''}>
                {match.url}
            </Link>
        </li>
        <Route path={`${match.url}/:path`} component={BreadcrumbsItem} />
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Excellent solution, but `span` cannot be a child of `ul`. Can we check if there are matching paths exists or not before rending `li` ?

Comment: Instead of `<span>`, I used `<React.Fragment>`.

Comment: @Jashwant I think `React.Fragment` was released after I posted this answer, but sure is a better approach today. Can you suggest an edit on the answer?

Comment: @Jashwant About the check before rendering `li`, `react-router` only renders routes that match. If for some reason you still want to check something before returning the `li`, I guess you could do a conditional or something like that.

Comment: Super elegant solution. Thank you a lot!

Comment: this becomes a problem when you have ID pages, like /students/:id it shows students twice

Answer (score 7):

I used `semantic-ui-react` for my own project and did this to create breadcrumbs based on `location.pathname`;

```
export default (props) => {
    const paths = props.pathname.split('/').map((p, i, arr) => {
        if (i === 0) return {
            key: i, 
            content: (<Link to={'/'}>home</Link>), 
            active: (i === arr.length - 1), 
            link: (i < arr.length - 1)
        };

        if (i === arr.length - 1) return {
            key: i, 
            content: p, 
            active: (i === arr.length - 1)
        };

        return {
            key: i, 
            content: (<Link to={`${arr.slice(0, i + 1).join('/')}`}>{p}</Link>), 
            active: (i === arr.length - 1), 
            link: (i < arr.length - 1)}
        };
    );
    return <Breadcrumb icon='chevron right' sections={paths}/>;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with both of these approaches is that you're limited to using the path name in the breadcrumb trail; that is, you have to tie your routing to the presentation names of your trail.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using a HOC that parses the `pathname` from react-router and returns matches against it. While a little more verbose, I think it gives greater flexibility and a nice readable breadcrumb config object array.

`Breadcrumbs.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withBreadcrumbs } from 'withBreadcrumbs';

const UserBreadcrumb = ({ match }) =>
  <span>{match.params.userId}</span>; // use match param userId to fetch/display user name

const routes = [
  { path: 'users', breadcrumb: 'Users' },
  { path: 'users/:userId', breadcrumb: UserBreadcrumb},
  { path: 'something-else', breadcrumb: ':)' },
];

const Breadcrumbs = ({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <div>
    {breadcrumbs.map(({ breadcrumb, path, match }) => (
      <span key={path}>
        <NavLink to={match.url}> // wrap breadcrumb with semantic-ui element
          {breadcrumb}
        </NavLink>
        <span>/</span>
      </span>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default withBreadcrumbs(routes)(Breadcrumbs);
```

`withBreadcrumbs.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { matchPath, withRouter } from 'react-router';

const renderer = ({ breadcrumb, match }) => {
  if (typeof breadcrumb === 'function') { return breadcrumb({ match }); }
  return breadcrumb;
};

export const getBreadcrumbs = ({ routes, pathname }) => {
  const matches = [];

  pathname
    .replace(/\/$/, '')
    .split('/')
    .reduce((previous, current) => {
      const pathSection = `${previous}/${current}`;

      let breadcrumbMatch;

      routes.some(({ breadcrumb, path }) => {
        const match = matchPath(pathSection, { exact: true, path });

        if (match) {
          breadcrumbMatch = {
            breadcrumb: renderer({ breadcrumb, match }),
            path,
            match,
          };
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      });

      if (breadcrumbMatch) {
        matches.push(breadcrumbMatch);
      }

      return pathSection;
    });

  return matches;
};

export const withBreadcrumbs = routes => Component => withRouter(props => (
  <Component
    {...props}
    breadcrumbs={
      getBreadcrumbs({
        pathname: props.location.pathname,
        routes,
      })
    }
  />
));
```

Open-source HOC is also available here:
https://github.com/icd2k3/react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17819984)

Comment: Fair enough @JagjotSingh! I edited my answer to include all relevant source code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple solution:

```
const Breadcrumbs = ({ ...rest, match }) => (
  <span>
      <Link to={match.url || ''} className={match.isExact ? 'breadcrumb active' : 'breadcrumb'}>
          {match.url.substr(match.url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, match.url.length)}
      </Link>
      <Route path={`${match.url}/:path`} component={Breadcrumbs} />
  </span>
)
```

Your css:

```
.breadcrumbs {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.breadcrumb {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 2.5;
  display: inline-block; 
}
.breadcrumb::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #818a91;
  content: "/"; }
.breadcrumb.active {
  color: #818a91; }
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div className="container-fluid breadcrumbs">
  <Route path='/:path' component={Breadcrumbs} />
</div>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: How do I remove the first / on the list? I have tried css for not the first child but that removes it of all of them

Comment: @Andrew you can use regex `replace(/^[/]/g, ' ')`

Answer (score 2):

From `react-router` doc: the `<Route>` component is rendering some of your components when a location matches the route’s path like this:

```js
<Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
```

Basic responsibility to the information is available to the rendered component which is `<Topic>` in this case. It knows how to fetch data or it already has tied Redux state and so on. So `<Topic>` simply instantiates the breadcrumbs item agent and passes the required data to it like this:

```js
import {BreadcrumbsItem} from 'react-breadcrumbs-dynamic'

const Topic = ({ match, topic }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>
      {topic.title}
    </h3>

    <BreadcrumbsItem to={`${match.url}/${match.params.topicId}`}>
      {topic.title}
    </BreadcrumbsItem>

    ...
  </div>
)
```

That's all. A fuller example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935917/7694876). Here is the live [demo](https://oklas.github.io/react-breadcrumbs-dynamic/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution providing single source of truth for nested navigation and breadcrumbs.

The example app is available on GitHub: https://github.com/sneas/react-nested-routes-example

Demo: https://sneas.github.io/react-nested-routes-example/

Navigation configuration:

```
export const navigation = [
  {
    path: "/",
    label: "All categories",
    content: () => <AllCategories />,
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/electronics",
        label: "Electronics",
        content: () => <Electronics />,
        routes: [
          {
            path: "/accessories",
            label: "Accessories",
            content: () => <Accessories />,
            routes: [
              {
                path: "/usb-cables",
                label: "USB cables",
                content: () => <UsbCables />
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: "/headphones",
            label: "Headphones",
            content: () => <Headphones />
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

We have to recursively flatten navigation and render it a flat array:

```
const routes = flattenRoutes(navigation);
return (<Router>
  {routes.map((route, index) => (
    <Route
      key={index}
      path={route.path}
      render={() => rouete.content}
    ></Route>
  ))}
</Router>);
```

Then build breadcrumbs out of the same navigation structure.