# Does anyone have a solution to dynamic breadcrumbs and react-router 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I couldn't find how to implement dynamic breadcrumbs with react-router v4

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380448/how-do-i-create-react-router-v4-breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0):

here are many solutions [Dynamic breadcrumbs using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126428/dynamic-breadcrumbs-using-react-router)

I personally suggest `react-breadcrumbs-dynamic` as the most flexible solution that you can use with other routers